# Trying to run a python script in task scheduler, but it breaks due to request.urlopen(url)

Tags: python, windows, url, scheduled-tasks

My script works in spyder, but when I try and run it in task schedular (using a bat file) it won't action. I believe the reason to be an issue with the URL request and that I might need to use URL Parser... Not sure how this would work for my code though. (API key is not mine but tester)

```
import urllib.request as request
import json
import pandas as pd

ETFS = ["VTI"]    

def Name (ticker):

    url = "https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/fundamentals/{ticker}.US?api_token=OeAFFmMliFG5orCUuwAKQ8l4WWFQ67YX".format(ticker=ticker)

    with request.urlopen(url) as response:

            source = response.read()
            data = json.loads(source)          

    type(data.get('General',{}).get('Name', []))
    len(data.get('General',{}).get('Name', []))
    Name = (data.get('General',{}).get('Name', []))
    return (Name)

resultname = list(map(Name, ETFS))

d = { "Ticker": ETFS, 'Name': resultname}
dfx = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
dfx.to_excel("Equity ETFs.xlsx")
```

Comment: Task Scheduler tasks each run under a specific logon account that you can change. I suspect, without testing, that the account this script is running under in Task Scheduler does not have sufficient permissions to make the URL request.

Comment: Don't use a batch script. The task should be explicitly defined using an absolute path to "python[w].exe", with the absolute path of the script as the argument. Since this task doesn't appear to need a console UI, use "pythonw.exe". Accessing `"https://eodhistoricaldata.com"` should not be a problem, even if you choose to run in the services session with an S4U batch logon (i.e. run whether the user is logged on or not, and do not store a password); that only prevents access to network resources that require the user's credentials.